# Unable to replicate database in pouchDB

Tags: timeout, couchdb, pouchdb

I'm trying a react native application using couchDB 2.1.1. PouchDB entry in package json looks like this:

```
"pouchdb": "^6.3.4",
"pouchdb-react-native": "^6.3.4",
```

Replication is as shown below:

```
const localDB = new PouchDB('employee');
const remoteDB = new PouchDB('http://username:password@localhost:5984/employee');

localDB.replicate.from(
  remoteDB,
  (err, response) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
  },
);
```

I get following error:

```
{"code":"ETIMEDOUT","status":0,"result":{"ok":false,"start_time":"...","docs_read":0,"docs_written":0,"doc_write_failures":0,"errors":[],"status":"aborting","end_time":"...","last_seq":0}}
```

Almost all the times this works fine when I run the app in debug mode. Tried ajax timeout as shown here [PouchDB ETIMEDOUT error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39534600/pouchdb-etimedout-error). This didn't work. Is there something that I'm supposed to look in my code? Please help.

Comment: CORS enabled on Couch?

Comment: @AlexisCôté: No. But this works at times. At times, I get the data replicated easily. But when it fails, it doesn't work for a couple of hours at least.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, the following fixed it for me:

1. Use your PC ip address instead of localhost
2. Configure your firewall
   to allow connections on port 5984 OR just disable it (Not
   recommended)